# Stopping the activity

Tags: android, performance

I have activity A and activity B. I am starting activity B from activity A. In my activity B, i have a button to stop the activity B. Should I call finish() or stop() to free all resources hold by activity B?

Answer (score 1):

you should go for `finish();`

cause `finish()` will be finish you current activity ,which is showing on screen in present.

and it will remove the `activity` from stack also.

Answer (score 0):

Resources should be freed on `onDestroy` or `onPause` if you absolutely need to free them. Most things (Views,...) won't need you to, though, as they're going to get collected by the GC.